# I get this weird symbol in my text in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, symbols

[image]

Is there something I can do so that symbol won't show anymore?  I do use to break tags in the text, at the end of the word "companies" and at the end of the word "growth".

I appreciate any help. :)

This is the css:

```
.homepage .simple .article-excerpt {
background: none;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 22px;
line-height: 30px;
color: #fff;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

and this is the html

```
<p class="article-excerpt">We work with the world’s great companies<br>
to catalyze profitable and sustainable growth<br>
through innovation.</p>
```

and this is how I'm pulling the text from WordPress:

```
<?php   if ( !empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) :
    the_excerpt();
    else :
                    false;
                endif;
            ?>
```

Comment: Looks like a stray control character. Maybe a lone CR without a LF. You don't happen to have a live version of the site? Or a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @MrLister It's a little known and rarely used alternate syntax for php:  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: You can use Fiddler's HEX view response inspector to see the exact bytes sent from the server to the client. This can help you find the errant character.